# Start Firebase Emulators for Firestore / Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase-tools

I have tried starting firebase firestore and realtime database emulators through both a personal project and the Firebase Emulator Suite Codelab located here:
(https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-emulator#0)
Working with the codelab, the command line prints the following after 'firebase emulators:start'

```
[....] codelab-initial-state % firebase emulators:start --import=./seed
i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore, hosting
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: database, pubsub, storage
⚠  Your requested "node" version "10" doesn't match your global version "17". Using node@17 from host.
i  firestore: Importing data from /Users/lucasfrench/Documents/emulators-codelab/codelab-initial-state/seed/firestore_export/firestore_export.overall_export_metadata
i  firestore: downloading cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.13.1.jar...
Progress: =====================================================================================================================================================================> (100% of 61MB)
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.
i  functions: Stopping Functions Emulator
i  firestore: Stopping Firestore Emulator
i  hub: Stopping emulator hub

Error: TIMEOUT: Port 8080 on localhost was not active within 60000ms
```

This is the same Error with my personal project utilizing the realtime database emulator. However, I do not have any issues starting emulators for other products such as the auth emulator or with accessing the UI emulator.

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2379). The workaround is to specify your localhost address (ex. `127.0.0.1`) instead of `localhost` and add a host attribute inside your firebase.json with 127.0.0.1 also.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2379#issuecomment-972852609

```
"firestore": {
    "port": 8080,
    "host": "127.0.0.1"
},
```